# Counting cells where time is less than the current hour

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have odd problem.  I need to count my data  based on two criteria that constantly changes.  I'm looking to count cells that the day of the week is monday and time is anything done prior to the current hour.
[image: simplified data set]

Assuming the above data set I'm looking for a way to count Monday prior to 1215
my answer should be 3.  The key is though I want Monday and 1215 to be more of a dynamic value so I can continue looking at this for multiple weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See these two help files:

- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-DDA3DC6E-F74E-4AEE-88BC-AA8C2A866842
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214094

Use the COUNTIFS formula, like this, `=COUNTIFS(C2:C11,"<"&F2,A2:A11,"="&F1)`, where F1 is the day of the week and F2 is the current hour. You can either input the current hour manually, or use the formula `=NOW()-TODAY()`.

[image: Formula in context]